# How to wire this 12v switch

Tags: switches, wiring, toggle-switch, indicator

I need to wire this switch, but I have no idea how. I thought I was buying a normal 3P rocker switch :)

The power source is 12v battery and the load is LED flashlight.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can control the LED of this switch separately from the actual switching.  If you apply +/- on the "3" contacts, then it will light up the LED on the switch.  Then "1"/"2" are the contacts for the switch, simply giving you an open/close.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it is what you wanted if you were looking for a 3 position switch.  It can be hard buying switches without fiddling with them first to make sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought I was buying a normal 3P rocker switch :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDiPJ2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) A 3P (3-pole) switch would have three independent contacts. (b) A 3P2T (3-pole, double-throw) switch would have three changeover contacts. (c) What you've got and how to wire it.*

You've purchased a 1PST (one-pole, single-throw) switch with built-in isolated indicator.

Comment: Don't forget to add a current limiting resistor (\$\approx 1k\Omega \$) in series with the LED. Otherwise the LED will die a sudden death.

Comment: Yes, I assumed it was a 12 V indicator but there's nothing in the datasheet to support that. I've added the resistor.

Answer (score 1):

It's an SPST rocker switch with a 1.85V 10mA LED as the status indicator.

The switch terminals are 1 & 2 and the indicator terminals 3+ & 3-.

The value of the LED voltage dropping resistor R would depend on the supply voltage.

[image]

Here are the cut-out details for mounting the switch.

[image]